# Back end of posts appear one letter piled by another letter in a vertical fashion

Tags: plugins

I deactivated all the plug ins, logged out and then logged back in.  Problem was fixed.  But when I activated Yoast SEO the problem appeared again.

Comment: Since you’ve found that the problem is the Yoast plugin you should contact its author for support.